# angularJS/breeze wipes out 'intermediate' negative number entry (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, breeze

Fighting a little bit of a battle here.  I have an HTML5 SPA app based on John Papa's methodology. I have a series of input boxes that are supposed to accept positive/negative real numbers.

Similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694415/using-angular-validation-directives-with-breeze-blocks-any-input-that-is-invalid), when a user types the first '-' key as part of a negative number, either breeze (1.5.2) or angularjs (1.3.15) wipes it out because it's not a valid number at that point.  Per the post, I added to the input the ng-model-options:

```
<input 
 ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
 ng-model="rdg.Reading.ManualValue"
 step="any" type="number"/>
```

and that helps, but the problem is that there are usability issues, as was mentioned in that post.  Previously, the moment pressed the first key, the view gets notification that something has changed and all is well.  Now you actually have to leave the control, which could lead to confusion.

There was a second suggestion, namely adding:

```
ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"
```

Which sounded conceptually way better, but this did not have any effect - hence back to the onBlur.

I could really use some advice on how to make this better.  OnBlur helped, but I can just hear the complaints I'm going to get because of this non-consistent way of entering numbers.

Thanks for any help.
Corey.

Comment: from what I can tell, this must be something in Breeze.  Angular doesn't have any issue with negative numbers, just taking their example on validation from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D#!/, opening it in Plunker, and removing the `min=` expression, negative numbers work fine.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more code, in particular how and where you let breeze persist the data to the server? Is there a Save button on your form?

Comment: here is a plunker that demonstrates the issue fairly well; it comes from the question linked to in this question.  http://plnkr.co/edit/dVsF7GFY65a30soLL5W8?p=preview In this sample, anything less than 4 characters breaks the textbox; in the poster's case, a negative causes the issue.  In both cases, data submission to the server is not necessary to break the boxes.

Comment: @flup I don't think this has nothing do to with data submission to the server, but remains solely within client-side Breeze validation.   I'm hoping that someone like Ward (the breeze guru) may be able to comment.  I'm going to try a custom validation function and see if that helps.

Comment: need more info. The Plunkr for the other example gave issues b/c of 2 reasons: 1) it was using minimum length, 2) populating an array so the current target was null. Your problem is different and using your markup in that Plunkr, I could not re-create your bug. Do you have some kind of active validation against this model in your controller?

Answer (score 2):

The input is getting reset when breeze parses and updates the entity. To prevent this from happening, you can add breeze's `z-float` angular directive to the input.

Add the script to the page:

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/Breeze/breeze.js.labs/master/breeze.directives.js" ></script>
```

Add the module as a dependency to your app:

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['breeze.directives']);
```

And add the `z-float` directive to your input:

```
<input data-ng-model="vm.person.balance" z-float placeholder="Balance" />
```

See http://www.getbreezenow.com/breeze-labs/breezedirectivesfloat

> The cause is Angular's eager data binding. Angular sends each keystroke through to the data bound model property.
>
> That becomes a problem when Breeze parses data entry before the user has finished typing. The user could be in the middle of data entry when Breeze parsing does something to her intermediate value and updates the property with something else before she has a chance to complete her thought.

For more details, and to see it in action, check out their [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E2HgF7ASNWIdwsvzs5G0)

Comment: @Claies Your problem is the other way around. Angular eagerly chops off the characters that get typed so they can never grow large enough. A different directive that tweaks the parsing, not the formatting, can help you there. See http://plnkr.co/edit/jFL73qyJhng8YrniqYTL?p=preview